# Getting list assignment index out of range in my code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to assign a value to a position in an existing list but I keep getting that my index is out of range. Probably something stupid but I have been 2 hours trying.

Here is my code (I'm getting the error from the last line:

```
test="2000 and was not However, implemented 1998 it until;9 8 3 4 1 5 7 2"
saver=[]
text=""
textList=[]
positionList=[]
num=0

for l in test.strip().split(";"):
    saver.append(l)
print saver
for i in saver[0].split(" "):
    textList.append(i)
print textList
for j in saver[1].split(" "):
    positionList.append(j)
print positionList

accomodator=[]*len(textList)

for n in range(1,len(textList)):
    n=int(n)
    if n not in positionList:
        accomodator[n-1]=textList[n-1]
```

Some variables I still havent used but I already declared them, so just ignore them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What line causes the error?

Comment: What is the lenght of `testList`? If it is 0, then it will cause out of index error as accomodator has zero length.

Comment: `[] * any_number` returns `[]`, according to my testing. Therefore your `accomodator` is empty.

Comment: how can I specify the amount of items there will be in a list before assigning any values to it? @Blorgbeard

Comment: use `[None] * any_number` instead (or any default value - zero, negative one..)

Comment: @FutoFarai: Length of accomodator is zero. Therefore, it is giving out of index error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
accomodator=[]*len(textList)
```

Because an empty list multiplied by any number is an empty list:

```
>>> [] * 10
[]
```

You can initialize each element with some default value:

```
>>> [None] * 10
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

So the fix for your code is:

```
accomodator=[None]*len(textList)
```

And of course, `0` or `-1` or any other value you like would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Length of `accomodator` is zero. It will give out of index error.

Try this:

```
accomodator=[]*len(textList)
#print str(len(accomodator)) + " "+str(len(textList))
i = 0;
while i<len(textList):
    accomodator.append([])
    i +=1
```

After creating `accomodator`, increase its length. Or if you know some efficient to increase its length, you can use it.

Comment: That sort of works, but you end up with an array like `[[],[],[],[]]` - you're adding an empty list as each element.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: I think intention is to create list of lists. That is why I suggest this way. Your answer appears efficient.

Comment: It looks like the code overwrites each value in the list anyway, so it probably doesn't matter what's in it :) Btw, `[[]] * len(textList)` would do the same as your code.